# Pipe successfully sorting data but tests are returning incorrect results

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am using a pipe to sort a a json array with two datetime columns in either ascending or descending order (triggered by the boolean `isDescending`, however the unit test doesn't seem to care about the order each object is in the array. Like in the test all 4 cases return true, even though the returned array should have the items in reverse order compared to `dummyData[]`. What am I doing wrong

sortpipe.ts

```
export class SortByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(data: iRepositories[], args?: ISortByPipe): iRepositories[] {
    if ( !args.column)
    {
      return data;
    }
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      if (args.isDescendingOrder)
      {
        return a[args.column] > b[args.column] ? -1 : 1;
      }
      else
      {
        return a[args.column] > b[args.column] ? 1 : -1;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

sortpipe.spec.ts

```
describe('SortByPipe', () => {

  let pipe: SortByPipe;

  beforeEach(() => {
    pipe =  new SortByPipe();
  });

  const dummyData = [
    { id: 1, created_at: '2014-01-24T13:40:11Z', updated_At: '2015-01-24T13:40:11Z' },
    { id: 2, created_at: '2015-01-24T13:40:11Z', updated_At: '2016-01-24T13:40:11Z' },
    { id: 3, created_at: '2016-01-24T13:40:11Z', updated_At: '2017-01-24T13:40:11Z' },
  ];

  it('create an instance', () => {
     expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // this is correct
  it('should return in the same order as the original data (sort by created_at date)', () => {
    const args: ISortByPipe = {column: 'created_at', isDescendingOrder: false};
    expect(pipe.transform(dummyData, args)).toEqual(dummyData);
  });

  // this is correct 
  it('should return in the same order as the original data (sort by last commit date)', () => {
    const args: ISortByPipe = {column: 'updated_At', isDescendingOrder: false};
    expect(pipe.transform(dummyData, args)).toEqual(dummyData);
  });


  // this should be false but its returning true
  it('should return in descending order (sort by created_at date)', () => {
    const args: ISortByPipe = {column: 'created_at', isDescendingOrder: true};
    expect(pipe.transform(dummyData, args)).toEqual(dummyData);
  });

  // this should be false but its returning true
  it('should return in descending order (sort by last commit date)', () => {
    const args: ISortByPipe = {column: 'updated_At', isDescendingOrder: true};
    expect(pipe.transform(dummyData, args)).toEqual(dummyData);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
let sortarray = [...data];
sortarray = sortarray.sort((a, b) => {
      if (args.isDescendingOrder)
      {
        return a[args.column] > b[args.column] ? -1 : 1;
      }
      else
      {
        return a[args.column] > b[args.column] ? 1 : -1;
      }
    });
return sortarray;
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts *in-place* so it sorts the array you pass in.  It returns the same array out of convenience but it is not making a copy of the input.  This means, after you call your transform, the order of `dummyData` has been changed.  You should make a copy in your pipe to keep it safe.